# Service pack and Cumulative Updates Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, service-pack

If i install SP3 for exchange 2010, would it include all the previous cumulative update?

Thanks

Comment: I just needed this question and the answer bellow :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.  Generally this is the case for Microsoft patches.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/02/12/released-exchange-server-2010-sp3.aspx -- "Yes. Service Packs are cumulative - they include all fixes included in previous RUs and service packs. Although Exchange 2010 SP2 RU6 was released on the same day as Exchange 2010 SP3, fixes in RU6 are included in SP3"

Comment: However that was not the case when I was configuring TMG2010. I had to install all of the updates and the rollups one by one.. That led me to ask myself this question..